# Edit/Remove existing File Manager (right-click/context menu) actions

Tags: gnome, nautilus, context-menu, nautilus-actions

Using classic Gnome and Nautilus with Ubuntu 18.04

I installed File-Manager-Actions, the replacement for Nautilus Actions.  It's fine for adding new actions.

But I want to EDIT the default actions.  Not the default OpenWith App, but for instance to move actions I never use (Compress, Send To and others) into a subfolder, or remove them altogether.

None of the suggestions online seem to apply to this version, I think things have been removed recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context menu items cannot be removed without going into the source code. Others are implemented by a nautilus extension. You can remove these by removing these extensions.

In a few cases, these extensions are installed by a dedicated package, like `nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal`, which provides the "Open in terminal" context menu. In that case, you can simply remove the package to remove the menu item.

In other cases, the extension is installed while installing a utility, e.g. the "Compres..." option is provided by `fileroller`. Removing that package will remove the right-click menu, but will also remove the archiving utility.

Some extensions are installed with the `nautilus`package itself.

All these extensions live as files in the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-3.0` folder. You can remove these files to remove the right-click functionality they provide, but the risks of directly interfering with system files is of course fully with the user.

Comment: Well, I renamed away extensions-3.0/libnautilus-sendto.so and it remobed the SendTo option.  Then did the same with libnautilus-fileroller.so but that had no effect, and as you suggest I don't want to remove Archive Manager completely.  I can live with it like this, otherwise I'd be looking for a new file manager,